# Typescript :Prevent implicit type conversion of Number to Array

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do I prevent implicit cast from number to array?

```
@Component
export default class FeedbackMain extends Vue {

currentState : Number = 0;

mounted () {
this.currentState = "Hello" //  Type '"Hello"' is not assignable to type 'Number'
this.currentState = data.filter(d => d.statetype === 0).map(d => d.state) // Not complaining
}
```

Comment: what about changing `currentState` to type any? --> `currentState: any;`

Answer (score 0):

That should give you an error, even for an array of `any`:

> Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Number': toFixed, toExponential, toPrecision

Where is your `data` variable coming from? If data is `any`, the result of that pipeline will also be `any` and assign to anything.

Comment: Ok. Defining data as an array will give the above mentioned error. But I just don't think it makes sense that I can  assign an array to a Number when it's clearly predefined.

Comment: You cannot, you simply can assign `any` to anything.